# Trying to find the circular reference in my django urlpatterns using django-subdomains?

Tags: python, django, django-subdomains

I'm getting a the url conf correct for my web app, and I'm at a loose end.

I *think* the idea behind [`django-subdomains`](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is that the subdomain routing is stored in the `SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS`

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'creativeflow'
# A dictionary of urlconf module paths, keyed by their subdomain.
SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS = {
    None: ROOT_URLCONF + '.urls',  # no subdomain, e.g. ``example.com``
    'www': ROOT_URLCONF + '.urls',
    'blog': 'blog.urls',
}
```

Then my `creativeflow.urls` and `blog.urls` are:

```
"""Creativeflow URL Configuration."""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
]
```

And

```
"""Creativeflow URL Configuration the blog app."""
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import BlogListView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'posts/^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<months>\d{2}|\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})',
        BlogListView.as_view(paginate_by=25), name="blog-list-view")
]
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x046FA618>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 419, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\creativeflow\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 426, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'creativeflow' does not appear to have any patterns in
 it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I'm assuming that, as you can see, I have an urlpatterns in both `urls.py`. So I must have a circular reference. But I've followed the imports from through `views.py` and `models.py` and I don't see anything that would cause a circular dependency problem.

How do I resolve this/and find the circular dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ROOT_URLCONF` points to a module without any patterns. The `ROOT_URLCONF`module must at least have a `urlpatterns` attribute, even if it's an empty list. You probably want this to point to `creativeflow.urls`.

Comment: Thanks, that's gotten me past that issue! I'll looks into the next one, I think it's to do with `blog.urls`. EDIT: the next one should just be `blog.urls`, and the `^` should be removed from the blogs url pattern